# Obscure field and modifier in Log4j Logger

Tags: java, bytecode

When looking into the class file for `org.apache.log4j.Logger` it defines a synthetic field of type `Class` with name `class$org$apache$log4j$Logger`.

From looking at the byte code, it is clear that this field represents the self-referenced class from a time where the constant pool could not yet reference types. What I do however find strange is the modifier of this field which is `0x41008` which indicates a `private`, `synthetic` field (that I can follow) but which adds a modifier `0x40000` which I cannot find documented anywhere.

Where does this modifier at bit 19 come from and what does it express? (Log4j is compiled for Java 1).

Comment: It’s not the constant pool which could not reference types, but the `ldc` instruction which could not load such a reference as `Class` object to the operand stack. But the class constant pool type already existed to allow specifying the `this` and `super` type, implemented interfaces and declaring classes of referenced members.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*javap* is perfectly happy with that class file:

```
  static java.lang.Class class$org$apache$log4j$Logger;
    descriptor: Ljava/lang/Class;
    flags: ACC_STATIC
    Synthetic: true
```

access_flags are supposed to be `u2`, meaning 2-byte unsigned. It is puzzling to see `0x41008`, which is larger than `u2`. Some tools are known to store access_flags in larger types, and inject auxiliary bits (ASM does it, JVMs do it, etc.) I know you are reading with ASM, so this is probably what you are looking at:

**org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.java:**

```
        } else if ("Synthetic".equals(attrName)) {
            access |= Opcodes.ACC_SYNTHETIC
                    | ClassWriter.ACC_SYNTHETIC_ATTRIBUTE;
```

**org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.java:**

```
/**
 * Pseudo access flag to distinguish between the synthetic attribute and the
 * synthetic access flag.
 */
static final int ACC_SYNTHETIC_ATTRIBUTE = 0x40000;
```

The question is, how does it leak to you...

Comment: It leaks by using IntelliJs plugin for reading byte code which is based upon ASM and not javap. Should have relied on the official tooling. Thanks!